# Static Variables and Performance

Tags: java, static, jvm, cpu

Do threads have to compete for ownership of a static variable or function? If so, does making variables or functions static degrade CPU performance? I understand there is utility in making things static so the CPU does not have to re-instantiate entities that can be shared.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "compete for ownership"?

Comment: Any object with multiple writers (or one writer and some readers) forces CPU cores to compete for ownership of the cache line containing it.  (MESI "exclusive" or "modified" states can only be held by one core at a time, stopping other cores from even being able to read).  Functions are read-only so all cores can read their JITed machine code in parallel.  (Once the JVM has finished JIT optimizing it.)  Same with data that's only read; read-only access scales basically perfectly with multiple threads and cores.  Of course if data isn't read-only, static or not changes behaviour!